# Load unpacked extensions in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to figure out how to load unpacked chrome extensions on my computer. I do not have administrator access, but can have my administrator do something if I need to. I go to chrome://extensions and have enabled developer mode. I see the option to "Pack extension" and "Update" but do not see the option to "Load unpacked". I assume this is something disabled by my administrator, but neither of us have been able to figure out how to enable it. Is there something that can be turned on/off to get this working? I am on Windows 10 and have Chrome 72.0.3626.109